# Quantitative tail sizing

Tags: descriptive-statistics

What is the most generic way of deciding whether the tail of a dataset is long or short? In other words, what would be the unit-free summary metric `m` that could be used in combination with two threesholds `s` and `l` to say:

- If `m < s` the dataset's tail is considered to be short
- If `m > l` the dataset's tail is considered to be long

This quantitative tail sizing would be used as an early step of an [Exploratory Data Analysis](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/eda.htm) process, and would come in support of graphical techniques like Histogram, [Probability Plot](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/probplot.htm), and [Probability Plot Correlation Coefficient Plot](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda33n.htm) that would be used to validate the selection of the best-fit distribution and the estimation of its parameters.

Comment: It really depends on *why* you are making this classification.  Different criteria emerge depending on how the tail influences the questions of importance to you.  What is the reason you are evaluating distribution tails?

Comment: To prepare for the selection of the distribution that would best fit a dataset. This quantitative tail sizing would be used as an early step of an Exploratory Data Analysis process.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't that just withhold an explanation?  In what sense should the fit be "best" and what are you seeking to find out with the EDA? It is noteworthy that you seem now to be talking about *data* rather than a *distribution*, too: they are quite different things. (Incidentally, an EDA won't "validate" anything: don't confuse exploration with confirmation!)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I really meant "dataset." What I am trying to do is exploration first, confirmation second. For example, if I know that the tail is short, I will not even bother considering the Cauchy Distribution as a possible candidate for my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for this as one aspect of curve fitting. In this case, you could compare the shape of your distribution to distributions you think might be right. You could plot overlaid density plots of your own distribution and others and compare that way, you could also look at QQ plots and other methods. There's been a lot on curve fitting here.

But "long" or "short" needs "compared to what?"

It will also matter if the tails are long on both sides or just one.